# Graphml generated from tinkerpop cannot be opened by yEd Graph Editor

Tags: tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint, tinkergraph, yed

I have saved a graph using the Tinkergraph API.

The file is here: https://pastebin.com/C81rZYa2

I was trying to open the file using yEd and I am getting the following error:

```
    at y.H.A.K.ā(Unknown Source)
    at y.H.H.ā(Unknown Source)
    at y.H.H.ā(Unknown Source)
    at y.H.G.ā(Unknown Source)
    at y.B.A.M.Đ(Unknown Source)
    at y.B.h.č(Unknown Source)
    at y.B.h.ā(Unknown Source)
    at y.B.h.ă(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.A.B.Z.ă(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.A.B.Z.ā(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.A.K.P.ā(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.A.K.P.ā(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.A.K.G.ā(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.A.K.G.ą(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.A.K.P$B.Ă(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.A.K.P.ā(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.A.L.D.ā(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.A.L.j.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at com.jidesoft.plaf.basic.BasicJideButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ParseException, did not find LETTER, EOF or ] but '<'
    at y.H.A.K.ă(Unknown Source)
    ... 55 more
```

Is there a version mismatch between yEd and Tinkergraph? I am using tinkerpop 2.6.0 i.e. the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
            <artifactId>blueprints-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: That is a really old version of TinkerPop - are you able to test with the latest version? The one you are using is many years old. Everything was renamed starting with TinkerPop 3 also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a version mismatch. Kelvin Lawrence suggested you are using an old version of TinkerPop. I think you may also be using an old version of yEd.

I have successfully opened your file using yEd v3.21.1 without any errors.

The nodes have the following custom properties:

- reference
- identifier
- modifier
- text
- type
- parentType

After installing a recent version version of yEd you probably also want to create a custom node that exposes some or all of these properties, otherwise there is nothing to distinguish the nodes.

The graph also appears to contain two loops - two nodes that link to themselves.